# How to calculate length of a side that is common in two triangles if the other lengths are known

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

[image]

Given two triangles ABC and BCD that share a common base BC, and have known lengths for sides AB, AC, BD and DC, how can I calcuate the length of side BC ?

Comment: You can't. Imagine this being a link with hinges. The points B and C can be moved toward each other or away from each other by a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you can say is:

1. From ABC, BC can be a minimum of 3 and a maximum of 11
2. From DBC, BC can be a minimum of 3 and a maximum of 13

Therefore $3\le BC\le 11$